# I am getting error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method"

Tags: android, nullreferenceexception

Hello Im newebie to android programming. I keep getting nullreference error when here. Im using Google Map API and using azure webservice. Im new to stackoverflow too thats why my question is in a mess and so does my grammar.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private double myLatitude, myLongitude;
private String myUrl;
private static Context context;
private Button set;
private EditText skillCari;
private TextView latlng;
private List<People> finalPeople = new ArrayList<>();
private List<People> myPeople = new ArrayList<>();
private double currentLatitude, currentLongitude;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
public Activity currentActivity = this;
private double minLatitude, maxLatitude, minLongitude, maxLongitude;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    MapsActivity.context = getApplicationContext();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000).setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);
    latlng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Latlng);
    RecyclerView myRecyle = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecycleView);
    myRecyle.setHasFixedSize(true);
    myRecyle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    final AdapterCard myCard = new AdapterCard();
    myRecyle.setAdapter(myCard);
    skillCari = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.skill_cari);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    final Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butSearch);
    set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myCard.clearData();
            BengService service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(BengService.class, BengService.BENG_SERVICE);
            service.getSkilledUser(skillCari.getText().toString())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<People>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            Log.e("GithubDemo", e.getMessage());
                            Log.e("GithubDemo", e.toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(List<People> peoples) {
                            finalPeople = SaringPeople(peoples, location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                            myCard.addData(finalPeople);
                            TambahMap(mMap, finalPeople);


                        }
                    });
        }
    });


}

 public ArrayList<People> SaringPeople(List<People> people, double userLatitude, double userLongitude) {
    myLatitude = userLatitude;
    myLongitude = userLongitude;
    myPeople = people;
    ArrayList<People> peopleSample = new ArrayList<>();
    double R = 6371;
    double radius = 0.300;
    double longitudeMin, longitudeMaks, latitudeMin, latitudeMaks;
    longitudeMin = (userLongitude - Math.toDegrees(radius / R / Math.cos(Math.toRadians(userLatitude))));
    longitudeMaks = (userLongitude + Math.toDegrees(radius / R / Math.cos(Math.toRadians(userLatitude))));
    latitudeMaks = (userLatitude + Math.toDegrees(radius / R));
    latitudeMin = (userLatitude - Math.toDegrees(radius / R));
    for (People myPeople : people) {
        if ((myPeople.getLatitude() <= latitudeMaks) && (myPeople.getLatitude() >= latitudeMin) && (myPeople.getLongitude() <= longitudeMaks) && (myPeople.getLongitude() >= longitudeMin)) {
            peopleSample.add(myPeople);
        }
        else{}
    }
    return peopleSample;

}

public void TambahMap(GoogleMap googleMap, List<People> people) {
    Bitmap urlImage;
    for (People mypeople : people) {
        urlImage = getBitmap(mypeople.getPhotoURL());
        LatLng haha = new LatLng(mypeople.getLatitude(), mypeople.getLongitude());
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(haha).title(mypeople.getFullName()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(urlImage)));

    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmap;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

  @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    } else {
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}
```

I am trying to running method "**TambahMap**" and "**SaringPeople**" by clicking button "**butSearch**" 
please help me..

Im getting this error from my log

```
09-26 00:16:04.018 6337-6337/com.example.beng.bengtuak E/GithubDemo: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
09-26 00:16:04.018 6337-6337/com.example.beng.bengtuak E/GithubDemo: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
09-26 00:16:16.386 6337-6337/com.example.beng.bengtuak E/GithubDemo: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
09-26 00:16:16.386 6337-6337/com.example.beng.bengtuak E/GithubDemo: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Sorry but without stack trace you wont get any reply

Comment: can u explain how can i use stack trace?
thanks

Comment: Assuming that you are using Android studio you should have thing called "Android Monitor", there will be tab called logcat.

Comment: i have put my logcat there in the last part

Comment: You need to connect the mGoogleApiClient using mGoogleApiClient.connect();
Please check the url for a step by step guide
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android

Answer (score 0):

It appears that location object that you are obtaining from googleclient is null

```
 final Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Add a callback for googleclient

```
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    }
```

You should be checking if that location is null and if so request location updates.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question @Adam

but i have implemented that method but still getting error
I didnt show it in my earlier snippet code 
I will edit my snippet code so i can show you all my activity code
thanks

Comment: You should read more about nullpointer here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it